# Pings disappearing in certain browsers?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, comments

Not sure if anyone else runs into this, but I occasionally am unable to ping people in comments if I use the mobile app or Safari. When I include `@username` at the beginning of a comment, it gets deleted when I actually try to post it.

I realize the mobile app is probably never going to be fixed, but I was curious if others have seen this with Safari and if so whether it can be fixed.

Comment: what makes you think pings do disappear?

Comment: . . . ZOMG ALIENS!!1!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that pinging may be deleted automatically if system considers it unnecessary; see [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) For example, here is my screenshot of Safari on MacOS Sierra:

[image: Editing a comment in Safari on MacOS 10.12]

I tried to ping you here, but upon publishing the ping has gone:

[image: Final appearance of a comment in Safari on MacOS 10.12]

This is an OS- and browser-independent intended behavior. As for mobile app, it hasn't been updated for years and probably shouldn't be used.